# How to make optaplanner a REST webservice

Tags: web-services, optaplanner, drools-planner

I just started using the Optaplanner as a way to do vehicle routing.
However I would like to expose the optaplanner as a web service (preferably REST).

Now I've read on several blogs that it can be done with Apache Camel.
However finding a decent example seems impossible.

Are there any known examples that I can look at or any tips on how to expose this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to expose it as a REST service:

- [RESTEasy](http://www.jboss.org/resteasy): Annotate your domain objects with JAXB annotations (to define the structure of the XML file send over HTTP). Then write a Java class with JAX-RS annotations (to define the available REST methods). RESTEasy has a good reference manual, it focusses on REST and it allows you to tailer to the REST interface exactly as your client would like it. Deploy to a servlet container (WildFly, Jetty, ...).
- Camel: See [camel-optaplanner documentation](http://camel.apache.org/optaplanner.html) and then camel's documentation (or book) about REST specifically and deploying camel. Note that the camel-optaplanner module is relative young, but it's unit tested and works.
- Other REST technologies in the Java ecosystem

Anyway, OptaPlanner doesn't care how you expose it as a REST service (so it doesn't hinder you either):

[image: integration]

Comment: Standard answer that I have seen before but it stil gets me nowhere. Any known working examples with camel or RESTeasy?

Comment: Let's just follow that RESTEasy link to the [RESTEasy examples](https://github.com/resteasy/Resteasy/tree/3.0.7.Final/jaxrs/examples). Those RESTEasy examples show how to go from a REST service to javabeans. The OptaPlanner examples show how to solve a planning problem represented as javabeans. Putting them together isn't rocket science :)

Comment: Thank you Geoffrey, Java isn't really my thing. That why I wanted the WS. Sorry if my last comment sounded harsh.